# Is GPU hardware shared between many different users

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have been using Compute engine with an instance to which I attached  Tesla K80 GPU. I notice,occasionally sharp performance drops of the graphics application I am running there. The app is always the same.Its workload doesn't change. So I suspect it has something to do with the current load on the hardware from other places. How does it work with Google Cloud regarding Compute engine instances? If the hardware is shared by multiple users, then is there a way to reserve it (even with extra costs) for my usage only?

Comment: AFAIK the GPU is not shared, but the CPU is!

Comment: So my 8 CPU cores are shared ?

Comment: Sure, but the hardware may have 24, 48 or even more cores.

Comment: But how likely is that the real time performance of my app is affected by overload of the CPU cores by other users?  Shouldn't Google take care that 'my' resources are mine?

Comment: Not terribly likely, but it's possible. You can always track CPU steal time and see for yourself if it is happening.

Comment: Could you provide some details on how to track that?

Answer (score 2):

You could track your CPU steal time by watching at %st on TOP command.

http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2013/07/25/understanding-cpu-steal-time-when-should-you-be-worried